# ffmpeg-normalize not working in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pip, paths

I have `ffmpeg-normalize` installed through pip3
It seems to work from the terminal but I need to run it through python subprocess.

Everytime I try to run it the error says:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ffmpeg-normalize: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the way of [`ffmpeg-normalize`](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-normalize/) installation. You have to adjust PATH variable.

In case of user's installation by

```
pip3 uninstall ffmpeg-normalize
```

you should add *`/home/$USER/.local/bin`* to PATH variable.

---

Or if you install it system-wide by

```
sudo pip3 install ffmpeg-normalize
```

then it will be available from `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg-normalize`.

Make sure that your PATH variable contains *`/usr/local/bin`* directory. Minimal reproducible PATH variable should be *`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`*.

Comment: Thank you so much. Ran it as admin and it worked